# Making 8 digits number in Excel by adding two zeros at the end of every code

Tags: excel, formatting

I have thousands of numbers in a column in Excel, which are in 6-digits format. I need all of them to be in 8-digits format by adding two zeros at the end of each number. Example- the number is 760810 and i need to have 76081000.

I would really appreciate, if anyone could share their ideas how to make it!

thanks

I tried formating cells in the customs category by adding this type "00000000". BUt this add two zeros at the beginning, making "00760810" and i need them at the end.

Comment: Try formatting `#\0\0`

Comment: Multiply column by 100

Comment: =CONCAT(CellReferance;"00") if it is text

Answer (score 1):

As JvdV mention in comment, you can apply cell format like `#\0\0` or can use `TEXT()` function like-

```
=TEXT(A1,"#\0\0")
```

[image]